# How to migrate a Magento Installation to localhost

Tags: magento, localhost, magento-1.6

I've been following several guides over the internet, but I still can't access my Magento (1.6) website from localhost ..

I dumped the DB and imported it to phpMyAdmin, copied the files from the server to my localhost (WAMP), updated local.xml and have been to the core_config_data table and changed web/unsecure/base_url to new URL & web/secure/base_url to new URL.

Is there anything else to do ?

I've seen that sometimes, in some guides, they're asking to go to `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and insert the following lines: 127.0.0.1 www.mydomain.com mydomain.com

But I already did this to www.localhost.com since I already have several websites I need to run from localhost, I don't want to change that ..

So when I launch the website from www.localhost.com/mywebsite I'm redirected to the old address and my browser says "Oops! Google Chrome could not find 'the old address' "

Any suggestion would be welcome :)

Comment: What is the old address?

Comment: ec2-174-129-114-249.compute-1.amazonaws.com is the old address, and the full error message is "Oops! Google Chrome could not find mag-lb1-300711436.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"

Comment: Have you deleted the var/cache directory?

Comment: Don't forget to change the URL in your database. The URL's for the site are in the core_config table. They are some of the first values in that table.

Comment: Clear your browser cache -- sometimes they cache a 301 redirect in the browser session. FYI Magento is also not supported on Windows... :)

Comment: @MarkShust, Magento runs on Windows (WAMP) just fine. At least it does on Wamp-Developer, Xampp, WampServer, and a few others. Or do you mean "paid offical support" provided by the company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as core_config_data.path values are updated correctly (double-check), the only other thing (besides Magento's PHP code) that could do a redirect is an .htaccess file with a RewriteCond and RewriteRule directive. This also could be present in the VirtualHost.

As another option, you could edit the Windows Hosts file, and resolve your old domain name to 127.0.0.1 and update your VirtualHost's ServerAlias line to include that domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check that web/cookie/cookie_path and web/cookie/cookie_domain are correctly set into the core_config_data table. I usually delete values of these 2 fields when switching from a server to another.

Also always think of disabling cache before dumping your DB as this can avoid some struggling too.